# Mock Callout fails when DML in ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, contentdocumentlink

I have a class where I am reading content from the DB and using the info I read to call out. I actually make 2 callouts (one to authenticate and one to upload).

When I insert a record of `ContentDocumentLink` the callout (the first one, the authentication one) fails with the treaded `You have uncommitted work pending.` error. If I comment out that line, the authentication and upload callouts work fine (meaning, using the Mocks I set up).  **Please note all the other tests in this class behave the same way**, I am just showing the `schedulable` method because it's the simplest to copy here.

Obviously, something is weird on that `ContentDocumentLink`, I suspect some sort of sharing-based async call is tripping me,

I tried moving the insert out of the `TestSetup` and into the method, using `runAs` (in both locations), and playing with `Test.Start` and `Test.Stop` in other places.

Has anybody seen this before? Ideas?

Test

```
@TestSetup
static void setup() {
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test';
    insert acc;

    <Do other stuff>

    ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();

    contentVersion.Title = 'Test Attachment';
    contentVersion.PathOnClient = 'Test.jpg';
    contentVersion.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content Data');
    contentVersion.IsMajorVersion = true;

    insert contentVersion;

    ContentDocument doc = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument LIMIT 1];

    ContentDocumentLink contentLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    contentLink.LinkedEntityId = acc.Id;
    contentLink.ContentDocumentId = doc.Id;
    insert contentLink; //If I comment this, it works
}

@IsTest
static void testSchedulable() {

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockSetupForSpringCM());

    Test.startTest();

    String CRON_TIME = '0 0 23 * * ?';

    System.schedule('Test Sched', CRON_TIME, new MigrateToSpringCMBatchable());

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: so - is there a trigger (or automation-driven invocable apex) on ContentDocumentLink that does a callout using an async transaction (future, queueable)?

Answer (score 0):

So basically this is a usual behaviour for callouts. They are throwing an error if you do them after a DML statement. This is done to avoid situations where you update external system and then rollback changes before they're committed to DB.

In tests I had a similar issue, but with mixed DML. I ended up with a messy workaround where I create problematic data in a future method and wait for it to execute by calling

```
Test.startTest();
Test.stopTest();
```

In your case I would try to do it like this:

1. Change the end of test setup to this

   ```
    ContentDocumentLink contentLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    contentLink.LinkedEntityId= acc.Id;
    contentLink.ContentDocumentId = doc.Id;
    insertFuture(JSON.serialize(contentLink));
    Test.startTest() ;
    Test.stopTest();
   ```

   }
2. insertFuture

   ```
   @future
     static void insertFuture(String jsonStr) {
            insert (SObject) JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, SOBject.class);
    }
   ```

I know using start and stop here is against the best practices, but worked for me. Although I just put everything including the data population in future method.

Comment: Did you even look at my code sample?

Comment: @Sebastian Kessel Yes. This is some crazy async stuff going on there under the hood. When I had the mixed DML issue I tried to put the data creation code in different places, but the only way it worked was to create data in future and wait for it. I do not guarantee this would work, but your issue seems similar.

Comment: Did you see how those two lines already exist in the test method? Where would you put them?

Comment: @Sebastian Kessel updated the answer with a sample, please take a look